# Why is my bounce animation so jumpy instead of smooth?

Tags: css, css-animations

I needed to implement infinite bounce effect using pure CSS, so I referred [this](https://coveloping.com/tools/css-animation-generator) site and ended up doing [this](https://jsfiddle.net/9t1ofrew/).

```css
.animated {
  -webkit-animation-duration: 2.5s;
  animation-duration: 2.5s;
  -webkit-animation-fill-mode: both;
  animation-fill-mode: both;
  -webkit-animation-timing-function: linear;
  animation-timing-function: linear;
  animation-iteration-count: infinite;
  -webkit-animation-iteration-count: infinite;
} 

@-webkit-keyframes bounce {
  0%, 20%, 40%, 60%, 80%, 100% {-webkit-transform: translateY(0);}
  50% {-webkit-transform: translateY(-5px);}
} 

@keyframes bounce { 
  0%, 20%, 40%, 60%, 80%, 100% {transform: translateY(0);}
  50% {transform: translateY(-5px);}
} 

.bounce { 
  -webkit-animation-name: bounce;
  animation-name: bounce;
}

#animated-example {
    width: 20px;
    height: 20px;
    background-color: red;
    position: relative;
    top: 100px;
    left: 100px;
    border-radius: 50%;
}

hr {
    position: relative;
    top: 92px;
    left: -300px;
    width: 200px;
}
```

```html
<div id="animated-example" class="animated bounce"></div>
<hr>
```

Now, my only problem is the bouncing element takes a longer rest before it starts bouncing again. How can I make it bounce smoothly just like the bounce effect we get by using **`jQuery.animate`**?

Answer (score 53, accepted):

The long rest in between is due to your keyframe settings. Your current keyframe rules mean that the actual bounce happens only between 40% - 60% of the animation duration (that is, between 1s - 1.5s mark of the animation). Remove those rules and maybe even reduce the `animation-duration` to suit your needs.

```css
.animated {
  -webkit-animation-duration: .5s;
  animation-duration: .5s;
  -webkit-animation-fill-mode: both;
  animation-fill-mode: both;
  -webkit-animation-timing-function: linear;
  animation-timing-function: linear;
  animation-iteration-count: infinite;
  -webkit-animation-iteration-count: infinite;
}
@-webkit-keyframes bounce {
  0%, 100% {
    -webkit-transform: translateY(0);
  }
  50% {
    -webkit-transform: translateY(-5px);
  }
}
@keyframes bounce {
  0%, 100% {
    transform: translateY(0);
  }
  50% {
    transform: translateY(-5px);
  }
}
.bounce {
  -webkit-animation-name: bounce;
  animation-name: bounce;
}
#animated-example {
  width: 20px;
  height: 20px;
  background-color: red;
  position: relative;
  top: 100px;
  left: 100px;
  border-radius: 50%;
}
hr {
  position: relative;
  top: 92px;
  left: -300px;
  width: 200px;
}
```

```html
<div id="animated-example" class="animated bounce"></div>
<hr>
```

---

Here is how your original `keyframe` settings would be interpreted by the browser:

- **At 0%** (that is, at 0s or start of animation) - `translate` by 0px in Y axis.
- **At 20%** (that is, at 0.5s of animation) - `translate` by 0px in Y axis.
- **At 40%** (that is, at 1s of animation) - `translate` by 0px in Y axis.
- **At 50%** (that is, at 1.25s of animation) - `translate` by 5px in Y axis. This results in a gradual upward movement.
- **At 60%** (that is, at 1.5s of animation) - `translate` by 0px in Y axis. This results in a gradual downward movement.
- **At 80%** (that is, at 2s of animation) - `translate` by 0px in Y axis.
- **At 100%** (that is, at 2.5s or end of animation) - `translate` by 0px in Y axis.

Answer (score 31):

Here is code not using the percentage in the keyframes.
Because you used percentages the animation does nothing a long time.

- 0% translate 0px
- 20% translate 0px
- etc.

How does this example work:

1. We set an `animation`. This is a short hand for animation properties.
2. We immediately start the animation since we use `from`  and `to` in the keyframes. from is = 0% and to is = 100%
3. We can now control how fast it will bounce by setting the animation time: `animation: bounce 1s infinite alternate;` the 1s is how long the animation will last.

```css
.ball {
  margin-top: 50px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  background-color: cornflowerblue;
  border: 2px solid #999;
  animation: bounce 1s infinite alternate;
  -webkit-animation: bounce 1s infinite alternate;
}
@keyframes bounce {
  from {
    transform: translateY(0px);
  }
  to {
    transform: translateY(-15px);
  }
}
@-webkit-keyframes bounce {
  from {
    transform: translateY(0px);
  }
  to {
    transform: translateY(-15px);
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="ball"></div>
```

Answer (score 5):

In case you're already using the transform property for positioning your element (as I currently am), you can also animate the top margin:

```
.ball {
  animation: bounce 1s infinite alternate;
  -webkit-animation: bounce 1s infinite alternate;
}

@keyframes bounce {
  from {
    margin-top: 0;
  }
  to {
    margin-top: -15px;
  }
}
```