# Add a bounce effect at the end of css translate

Tags: javascript, css, animation

I'm using requestanimationframe and a css `transform: translateX` to move an image across the screen on scroll. I want to add a "bounce" effect at the end of the scroll. If I were using jQuery I could just add easing to the animation, but I'm pulling jQuery out of the animation.

I'd rather not use another library, is there a way to achieve a "wobble" effect using pure CSS?

Comment: Yes, `@keyframe` animation this Possible duplicate has CSS for for bounce effects in the question and answer you should be able to use as a base to start with ► [CSS smooth bounce animation](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32306089/css-smooth-bounce-animation)

Comment: look at this: http://cubic-bezier.com/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can totally do it with pure CSS. Check out the basic keyframes example below. You can easily tweak it to make it faster, smoother, longer, etc.

```css
#bouncingObject {
    /* Regular CSS for the object */
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    background-color: red;
    position: absolute;
    top: 200px;

    /* Handling the animation */
    -webkit-animation-name: bounce;
    -webkit-animation-duration: 2s;
    animation-name: bounce;
    animation-duration: 2s;
}

/* Defining the animation by dividing it to keyframes */
@keyframes bounce {
    0%   {top:0px;}
    25%  {top:200px;}
    40%  {top:150px;}
    55%  {top:200px;}
    70%  {top:180px;}
    85%  {top:200px;}
    100% {top:200px;}
}

/* This is for Safari 4.0 - 8.0 */
@-webkit-keyframes bounce {
    0%   {top:0px;}
    25%  {top:200px;}
    40%  {top:150px;}
    55%  {top:200px;}
    70%  {top:180px;}
    85%  {top:200px;}
    100% {top:200px;}
}
```

```html
<div id="bouncingObject"></div>
```