# How do I add an animated bounce with jQuery?

Tags: jquery, html, animation

I feel like I have the correct code in order for this to work, but it just isn't doing anything. Am I missing something?

```
$(document).ready(function() {
$("h2").addClass("animated bounce");
});
```

Here is my HTML as well.

```
<head>
<title>Brandon Stranc | Front End Developer</title>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, shrink-to-fit=no"> <!-- to scale well with mobile -->

<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="_css/style.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-beta/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-/Y6pD6FV/Vv2HJnA6t+vslU6fwYXjCFtcEpHbNJ0lyAFsXTsjBbfaDjzALeQsN6M" crossorigin="anonymous">

<!-- <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script> -->
<!-- <script src="_js/script.js"></script> -->
</head>
```

```
<header id="header">
    <div class="overlay">
    <nav>

        <a href="#projects" class="slide-section" title="">Projects</a>

        <a href="#about-me" class="slide-section" title="">About Me</a>

        <a href="#contact" class="slide-section" title="">Contact</a>
    </nav>

    <h2>Front End Developer</h2>
    <h4>Making Websites for BB &hearts;</h4>
    </div>
</header>
```

Comment: Can you make jsfiddle ?

Comment: If you may like [CSS Bounce](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32306089/css-smooth-bounce-animation)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> add [animate.css](https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/animate.css/3.5.2/animate.min.css) in page

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
$("h2").addClass("animated bounce");
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/animate.css/3.5.2/animate.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<header id="header">
    <div class="overlay">
    <nav>

        <a href="#projects" class="slide-section" title="">Projects</a>

        <a href="#about-me" class="slide-section" title="">About Me</a>

        <a href="#contact" class="slide-section" title="">Contact</a>
    </nav>

    <h2 >Front End Developer</h2>
    <h4>Making Websites for BB &hearts;</h4>
    </div>
</header>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think its a problem with the class name for the animated bounce.
When I did some research, I found the `animate.style` site and they had some
ways to animate bounce.

This is the work around that I did to implement this.

```
<head>
<!--Add this to the head element-->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/animate.css/4.1.1/animate.min.css"/>

<!--Make sure that you have the scripts to jquery -->
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.6.1.min.js" integrity="sha256-o88AwQnZB+VDvE9tvIXrMQaPlFFSUTR+nldQm1LuPXQ=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.6.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

```
</head>
```

I added the `.addClass()` function with the `animate__animated` `animate__bounce` class name that gets to be assigned to the h2. 
https://codepen.io/rodrigo-lopez/pen/MWGepmV

Hope this helps.